# Range using date with microsecond precision in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

If I stored a date as a [serial number](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DateTimeRenderOption#ENUM_VALUES.SERIAL_NUMBER) in javascript, for example, the date `"2014-01-01"` would be stored as `41640`., `"2014-01-01 12:00:00"` would be stored as `41640.5`, etc.

If we allowed microsecond precision (and not millisecond precision, like the current Javascript date object has), what would be the largest date that could be stored using the javascript Number?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are normal IEEE 754 double-precision (64 bit) floating point values, so this should be pretty easy to compute.

Comment: Also note that the question is somewhat ambiguous because it's not clear how much you care about losing precision beyond the largest representable integer; even before that you'll run out of precision for time-within-day.

Comment: @Pointy I thought the float in javascript has 53 bits?

Comment: No, they're ordinary 64-bit double-precision floating point values. You're thinking of the mantissa size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a day, there are 24*3600*10^6 μs and to store this value of 86400000000=0x141DD76000 accurately, one needs 37 bits.

There are 52+1 bits in the mantissa. So you have 16 bits left to code the day. This allows to code ~2^16/365=179 years and 201 days. As the reference is around 1900, we must also consider the leap years: 24(1900-1999)+20(2000-2079)=48 leap years.

As the reference is precisely december 30th 1899, the coding limit is reached on the dec 30th 2178 + (201-48) days that corresponds to june 2nd 2079.

After that, coding will continue with a loss of accuracy and will not precise at the microsecond.